# Query to $unwind $group and $match with mongo db

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql, aggregation-framework

I am trying to find solution to this query, I am using `$group, $match`.

This would be the collection:

```
PlayerTournament: [
    {
      "_id": 1,
      "Name": "John Aims",
      "Gender": "M",
      "DoB": ISODate("1990-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
      "Nationality": "USA",
      "Hand": "R",
      "YearTurnedPro": 2010,
      "Tournament": [
        {
          "TournamentYear": 2016,
          "TournamentCode": "GS1",
          "Position": 8,
          "PrizeMoney": 125000,
          "RankingPoints": 250
        },
        {
          "TournamentYear": 2019,
          "TournamentCode": "GS4",
          "Position": 2,
          "PrizeMoney": 625000,
          "RankingPoints": 1000
        },
        {
          "TournamentYear": 2021,
          "TournamentCode": "GS3",
          "Position": 4,
          "PrizeMoney": 312500,
          "RankingPoints": 500
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": 2,
      "Name": "George Brown",
      "Gender": "M",
      "DoB": ISODate("1997-03-04T00:00:00Z"),
      "Nationality": "GB",
      "Hand": "L",
      "YearTurnedPro": 2013,
      "Tournament": [
        {
          "TournamentYear": 2016,
          "TournamentCode": "GS1",
          "Position": 4,
          "PrizeMoney": 250000,
          "RankingPoints": 500
        },
        {
          "TournamentYear": 2019,
          "TournamentCode": "GS3",
          "Position": 2,
          "PrizeMoney": 625000,
          "RankingPoints": 1000
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": 3,
      "Name": "Kate Upson",
      "Gender": "F",
      "DoB": ISODate("1999-12-07T00:00:00Z"),
      "Nationality": "GB",
      "Hand": "L",
      "YearTurnedPro": 2013,
      "Tournament": [
        {
          "TournamentYear": 2016,
          "TournamentCode": "GS1",
          "Position": 1,
          "PrizeMoney": 1000000,
          "RankingPoints": 2000
        },
        {
          "TournamentYear": 2019,
          "TournamentCode": "GS1",
          "Position": 4,
          "PrizeMoney": 250000,
          "RankingPoints": 500
        },
        {
          "TournamentYear": 2020,
          "TournamentCode": "GS4",
          "Position": 2,
          "PrizeMoney": 625000,
          "RankingPoints": 1000
        },
        {
          "TournamentYear": 2017,
          "TournamentCode": "GS2",
          "Position": 2,
          "PrizeMoney": 625000,
          "RankingPoints": 1000
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": 4,
      "Name": "Mary Bones",
      "Gender": "F",
      "DoB": ISODate("1998-10-04T00:00:00Z"),
      "Nationality": "AUSTRALIA",
      "Hand": "L",
      "YearTurnedPro": 2015,
      "Tournament": [
        {
          "TournamentYear": 2018,
          "TournamentCode": "GS3",
          "Position": 1,
          "PrizeMoney": 1250000,
          "RankingPoints": 2000
        },
        {
          "TournamentYear": 2019,
          "TournamentCode": "GS2",
          "Position": 2,
          "PrizeMoney": 625000,
          "RankingPoints": 1000
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": 5,
      "Name": "Yuri Roza",
      "Gender": "M",
      "DoB": ISODate("2000-05-11T00:00:00Z"),
      "Nationality": "BELARUS",
      "Hand": "R",
      "YearTurnedPro": 2018,
      "Tournament": [
        {
          "TournamentYear": 2020,
          "TournamentCode": "GS4",
          "Position": 4,
          "PrizeMoney": 250000,
          "RankingPoints": 500
        },
        {
          "TournamentYear": 2018,
          "TournamentCode": "GS2",
          "Position": 4,
          "PrizeMoney": 312500,
          "RankingPoints": 500
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

This is what I tried.

```
db.PlayerTournament.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$Tournament"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "Tournament.TournamentYear": {
        $gte: 2020
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        Name: "$Name"
      },
      "total_qty": {
        "$sum": "$Tournament.PrizeMoney"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

I am getting all the player that have won something after the year `2020`.

I am looking to select the players' name of those that won more than `500000`(prizemoney) after the year `2020`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need one more `$match` stage to filter grouped results:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$unwind": "$Tournament"
    },
    {
        $match: {
            "Tournament.TournamentYear": {
                $gte: 2020
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": {
                Name: "$Name"
            },
            "total_qty": {
                "$sum": "$Tournament.PrizeMoney"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$match": { "total_qty": { "$gte": 500000 } }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RerYWAKbdGS)

Comment: Wow... You are still here to help people... Was away for a long but nice to see you again :-)